# Python pandas: remove everything after a delimiter in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have data frames which contain e.g.:

```
"vendor a::ProductA"
"vendor b::ProductA"
"vendor a::Productb"
```

I need to remove everything (and including) the two :: so that I end up with:

```
"vendor a"
"vendor b"
"vendor a"
```

I tried str.trim (which seems to not exist) and str.split without success.
what would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: `str.split` can do it - how did you try it?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can use `pandas.Series.str.split` just like you would use `split` normally. Just split on the string `'::'`, and index the list that's created from the `split` method:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ["vendor a::ProductA", "vendor b::ProductA", "vendor a::Productb"]})
>>> df
                 text
0  vendor a::ProductA
1  vendor b::ProductA
2  vendor a::Productb
>>> df['text_new'] = df['text'].str.split('::').str[0]
>>> df
                 text  text_new
0  vendor a::ProductA  vendor a
1  vendor b::ProductA  vendor b
2  vendor a::Productb  vendor a
```

Here's a non-pandas solution:

```
>>> df['text_new1'] = [x.split('::')[0] for x in df['text']]
>>> df
                 text  text_new text_new1
0  vendor a::ProductA  vendor a  vendor a
1  vendor b::ProductA  vendor b  vendor b
2  vendor a::Productb  vendor a  vendor a
```

Edit: Here's the step-by-step explanation of what's happening in `pandas` above:

```
# Select the pandas.Series object you want
>>> df['text']
0    vendor a::ProductA
1    vendor b::ProductA
2    vendor a::Productb
Name: text, dtype: object

# using pandas.Series.str allows us to implement "normal" string methods 
# (like split) on a Series
>>> df['text'].str
<pandas.core.strings.StringMethods object at 0x110af4e48>

# Now we can use the split method to split on our '::' string. You'll see that
# a Series of lists is returned (just like what you'd see outside of pandas)
>>> df['text'].str.split('::')
0    [vendor a, ProductA]
1    [vendor b, ProductA]
2    [vendor a, Productb]
Name: text, dtype: object

# using the pandas.Series.str method, again, we will be able to index through
# the lists returned in the previous step
>>> df['text'].str.split('::').str
<pandas.core.strings.StringMethods object at 0x110b254a8>

# now we can grab the first item in each list above for our desired output
>>> df['text'].str.split('::').str[0]
0    vendor a
1    vendor b
2    vendor a
Name: text, dtype: object
```

I would suggest checking out the [pandas.Series.str docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.html), or, better yet, [Working with Text Data in pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html).

Comment: I tried str.split('::') before without success. What does the .str[0] do at the end?

Comment: It takes the first argument of each list and returns it (str[0] = "vendor a", "vendor b", "vendor c", str[1] would be "ProductA", "ProductB", "ProductC")

Comment: how would you apply this for multiple columns?

Answer (score 10):

If it is in a specific column *(having name: column)* of a data frame *(having name: dataframe)*, you can also use

```
dataframe.column.str.replace("(::).*","")
```

It gives you the below result

```
         column        new_column       
0  vendor a::ProductA  vendor a
1  vendor b::ProductA  vendor b
2  vendor a::Productb  vendor a
```

By using this you need not specify any position, as it gets rid of anything present after '**::**'

I guess this might come oh help,Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str.replace(":", " ")` to remove the `"::"`.
To split, you need to specify the character you want to split into: `str.split(" ")`

The trim function is called strip in python: `str.strip()`

Also, you can do `str[:7]` to get just `"vendor x"` in your strings.

Good luck

Comment: can't do str[:7] as the vendor names have different length

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) which returns the part of the string inside the parenthesis:

```
In [3]: df.assign(result=df['column'].str.extract('(.*)::'))
Out[3]: 
               column    result
0  vendor a::ProductA  vendor a
1  vendor b::ProductA  vendor b
2  vendor a::Productb  vendor a
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the str.split function with flag expand=True and number of split n=1, and provide two new columns name in which the splits will be stored (expanded)
Here in the code I have used the name cold_column and expaned it into two columns as "new_col" and "extra_col". new_col contains the value needed from split and extra_col contains value noot needed from split.
Therefore finally drop the extra_col

code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'old_col': ["vendor a::ProductA", "vendor b::ProductA", "vendor a::Productb"]})
df[['new_col','extra_col']] = df['old_col'].str.split("::",n=1,expand=True)
df.drop('extra_col', axis=1, inplace=True)
df
```

output:

```
    old_col             new_col
0   vendor a::ProductA  vendor a
1   vendor b::ProductA  vendor b
2   vendor a::Productb  vendor a
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow. Please provide a description of how your answer solves the problem and provide references where appropriate.

Comment: @DaveL17, added some description to the code. kindly excuse as a new user of SOF

Comment: That's quite alright.  Thanks for updating your answer and thanks for taking the time to contribute.