# Pandas, remove everything after last '_'

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following kind of strings in my column seen below. I would like to parse out everything after the last `_` of each string, and if there is no `_` then leave the string as-is. (as my below try will just exclude strings with no `_`)

so far I have tried below, seen here: [Python pandas: remove everything after a delimiter in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40705480/python-pandas-remove-everything-after-a-delimiter-in-a-string) . But it is just parsing out everything after first `_`

`d6['SOURCE_NAME'] = d6['SOURCE_NAME'].str.split('_').str[0]`

Here are some example strings in my SOURCE_NAME column.

```
Stackoverflow_1234
Stack_Over_Flow_1234
Stackoverflow
Stack_Overflow_1234
```

Expected:

```
Stackoverflow
Stack_Over_Flow
Stackoverflow
Stack_Overflow
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a combination of `str.rsplit` and `str.get` for your desired outcome. `str.rsplit` simply splits a string from the end, while `str.get` gets the nth element of an iterator within a pd.Series object.

---

#### Answer

`d6['SOURCE_NAME'] = df['SOURCE_NAME'].str.rsplit('_', n=1).str.get(0)`

the `n` argument in `rsplit` limits number of splits in output so that you only keep everything before the last '_'.

Even though a solution using `pd.Series.apply` is almost half as fast, I like this one because is more expressive in it's syntax. If you want to use the `pd.Series.apply` solution (faster) check the timing part!

[pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html).

---

#### Example

```py
strs = ['Stackoverflow_1234',
        'Stack_Over_Flow_1234',
        'Stackoverflow',
        'Stack_Overflow_1234']
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'SOURCE_NAME': strs})
```

This results in

```
print(df)
            SOURCE_NAME
0    Stackoverflow_1234
1  Stack_Over_Flow_1234
2         Stackoverflow
3   Stack_Overflow_1234
```

Using the proposed solution:

```py
df['SOURCE_NAME'].str.rsplit('_', 1).str.get(0)

0      Stackoverflow
1    Stack_Over_Flow
2      Stackoverflow
3     Stack_Overflow
Name: SOURCE_NAME, dtype: object
```

#### Time

Interestingly, using `pd.Series.str` is not necessarily faster than using `pd.Series.apply`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'SOURCE_NAME': ['stackoverflow_1234_abcd'] * 1000})

%timeit df['SOURCE_NAME'].apply(lambda x: x.rsplit('_', 1)[0])
497 µs ± 30.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df['SOURCE_NAME'].str.rsplit('_', n=1).str.get(0)
1.04 ms ± 4.27 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# increasing the number of rows x 100
df = pd.concat([df] * 100)

%timeit df['SOURCE_NAME'].apply(lambda x: x.rsplit('_', 1)[0])
31.7 ms ± 1.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df['SOURCE_NAME'].str.rsplit('_', n=1).str.get(0)
84.1 ms ± 6.88 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Hi @excelguy. `n=1` is an argument on the `pd.Series.str.rsplit` method, which has its counterpart on vanilla Python as `str.rsplit`, with the vanilla argument being `maxsplit=1`.

These arguments simply limit the number of splits, **from the right**. Notice that the default value for these arguments is `-1`, which means *do not* limit the number of splits. If I say `pd.Series.str.rsplit(sep='_', n=1)` I am saying, split on '_' and split on the first '_' it finds from the right.

Open a terminal and try `'x_k_c_d'.rsplit(sep='_', maxsplits=1)`. Try different values for `maxplits`

Answer (score 1):

you could try applying lambda as such:

```
d6['SOURCE_NAME'] = df['SOURCE_NAME'].apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[0])
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Using rsplit() returns what you want to achieve, you can tell it how many times to split your string.

```
s = "Stack_Over_Flow_1234"
s.rsplit('_', 1)[0] # Split my string one time and get the first part of it
```

This then returns `'Stack_Over_Flow'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string.split('_') function to split the string into a list of substrings around every underscore, then recombine them without the last element. Here is a snippet using your examples:

```
a = ["Stackoverflow_1234", "Stack_Over_Flow_1234", "Stackoverflow", "Stack_Overflow_1234"]

for e in a:

    # Split the string into a list, separated at '_'
    splitStr = e.split("_")

    # If there is only 1 element, we can use it directly
    if len(splitStr) == 1:
        print(splitStr[0])

    # Slice off the final substring and join the remaining 
    # substrings back together with underscores
    else:
        print("_".join(splitStr[:-1]))
```