# How to remove symbols after delimiter (.) in every row of column [2] in csv file?

Tags: python, csv

How to remove symbols after delimiter (.) in each row of column [2] in csv file?

File structure:

```
Date, Time, Open, High, Low, Last, Volume, NumberOfTrades, BidVolume, AskVolume
2019/12/30, 14:38:01, 3233.00, 3233.00, 3230.00, 3233.00, 1, 1, 0, 1
2019/12/30, 14:38:01.1, 3233.25, 3233.00, 3230.00, 3233.25, 2, 1, 0, 2
2019/12/30, 14:43:13, 3230.00, 3230.25, 3230.00, 3230.00, 1, 1, 1, 0
2019/12/30, 15:12:47, 3224.50, 3224.75, 3224.50, 3224.50, 2, 1, 2, 0
2019/12/30, 15:12:47.1, 3224.50, 3224.75, 3224.50, 3224.50, 2, 1, 2, 0
2019/12/30, 15:12:47.2, 3224.50, 3225.50, 3224.50, 3224.50, 2, 1, 2, 0
2019/12/30, 15:12:58, 3224.50, 3225.50, 3224.50, 3224.50, 2, 1, 2, 0
2019/12/30, 15:13:14, 3224.50, 3224.75, 3224.50, 3224.50, 2, 1, 2, 0
2019/12/30, 15:13:14.1, 3224.50, 3225.25, 3224.50, 3224.50, 2, 1, 2, 0
```

The task is to remove milliseconds (.1, .2, .33, .444, etc.) in a second column 'Time'

> ```
> 14:38:01.1 edit to 14:38:01
> 14:43:13 do not edit
> 15:12:47.1 edit to 15:12:47
> 15:12:47.2 edit to 15:12:47 
>
> 00:00:00.123 edit to 00:00:00
> ```

Files are very large, so the amendments should be made with creating other .csv file, not updating the original one.

```
import csv
f = open('Book1.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
```

I'm stuck here.

I've tried, but it's not a solution.

```
row[2] = row[2][:-4]
```

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40705480/python-pandas-remove-everything-after-a-delimiter-in-a-string for reference

Comment: A reminder that Python uses zero indexing, so the time is actually in `row[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `split()`

Edit: changed row[2] to row[1], the question is wrong and I went with question's flow

```py
row[1] = row[1].split(".")[0]
```

Comment: ``try except`` would be redudant ``"14:38:01".split(".") => ['14:38:01']`` & ``"14:38:01.01".split(".") => ['14:38:01', '01']``

Comment: It seems to work fine! Thanks a lot! The only question left for me is how to save it as .csv without rewriting the original file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) you can use `converters` argument in [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('book1.csv', converters={' Time': lambda x:x[:9]})

         Date       Time     Open  ...   NumberOfTrades   BidVolume   AskVolume
0  2019/12/30   14:38:01  3233.00  ...                1           0           1
1  2019/12/30   14:38:01  3233.25  ...                1           0           2
2  2019/12/30   14:43:13  3230.00  ...                1           1           0
3  2019/12/30   15:12:47  3224.50  ...                1           2           0
4  2019/12/30   15:12:47  3224.50  ...                1           2           0
5  2019/12/30   15:12:47  3224.50  ...                1           2           0
6  2019/12/30   15:12:58  3224.50  ...                1           2           0
7  2019/12/30   15:13:14  3224.50  ...                1           2           0
8  2019/12/30   15:13:14  3224.50  ...                1           2           0

[9 rows x 10 columns]
```

Answer (score -1):

Read the file using pandas dataframe and then use below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv')
df['Time'] = df['Time'].str.split('.').str[0]
```

Comment: The OP isn't using Pandas, so if you're going to suggest a Pandas solution, you should provide the other lines of code needed to make it work, along with an explanation.

Comment: The question is not tagged pandas. This is a code only response not using OP's module . Please edit it with an explaination on why you think OP should use pandas here, or remove it.