# Remove text after a delimiter (parenthesis) in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to remove the text after "(" delimiter, firts I would like count the rows that have a least one "(" and after that, remove the text after this delimiter, including the delimiter.

**The column that contains the text is 'Country' and look like this:**

```
Micronesia (Federated States of)
```

**I hope a result like this:**

```
Micronesia
```

**this is what i tried to count rows**

```
energy['Country'].value_counts()[['(']].sum
```

**It returned this error:**

```
"None of [Index(['('], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

**for removing thext after delimiter I tried this:**

```
energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].split("(", 1)
```

**It returned this error:**

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: Try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40705480/python-pandas-remove-everything-after-a-delimiter-in-a-string), after replacing the ":" with your "(".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply `str.split` to the column, then take the first element with `.str[0]` and remove leading/trailing spaces with `str.strip`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['Micronesia (Federated States of)']})

df['country'] = df['country'].str.split('(').str[0].str.strip()
df
```

Output:

```
      country
0  Micronesia
```

---

And another (less verbose) option with `str.extract`:

```
df['country'] = df['country'].str.extract('(.*)\s*\(')
```

Comment: Hi, It gives me this error: Can only use .str accessor with string values! If I check the column type It says object, I have tried to convert it to a string by applying this: energy.Country.apply(str) but It still continue to be object, How could I convert it to a string?

Comment: @JhoanZuluaga Please try with `df['country'].astype(str).str.extract('(.*)\s*\(')`

Comment: It works @perl, the only thing missing is there are spaces at the final of the string, any idea? "Bolivia " instead of "Bolivia"

Comment: @JhoanZuluaga Let's try this: `df['country'].astype(str).str.extract('([^\(]*)', expand=False).str.strip()`

Comment: Or as another option: `df['country'].astype(str).str.extract('([^\(]*[^\(\s]+)')`

Comment: It works, I just found that some strings contain numbers, do you know how to delete them?

Comment: @JhoanZuluaga Try adding `str.replace('\d', '')`

Answer (score 2):

Using `.str.replace` with regex.

**Ex:**

```
energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].str.replace(r"(\(.*\))", "")
```

Comment: Hi, It gives me this error: Can only use .str accessor with string values! If I check the column type It says object, I have tried to convert it to a string by applying this: energy.Country.apply(str) but It still continue to be object, How could I convert it to a string?

Comment: `energy['Country'].astype(str).str.replace(r"(\(.*\))", "")`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will do this on every row instead of every column

```
for index,row in reviews.iterrows():
    print(energy['Country'].split("(")[0])
```

If you want to do this on specific row you can do

```
print(energy['Country'][0].split("(")[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate on each row and remove text after '(' using `str` slicing  :

```py
p_count=0
for index,row in energy.iterrows():
    if '(' in row['Country']:
        p_count+=1    
        row['Country']=row['Country'][:row['Country'].find('(')].strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

that's because you trying to split a series not the values of the rows .
instead of that use this:

```
energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].apply(lambda x:x.split('(',1))
```

this should grab what ever after "(" delimiter and if you want to remove after it you can use this:

```
energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].apply(lambda x:x.replace(x.split('(',1),''))
```