# Make changes in the row data in excel panda

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to change the data in a row
database:

| Name | City | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Toronto,Canada | Canada |
| Smith | Seattle,United States | United States |
| Raj | Greater Toronto Area,Canada | Canada |

The Records in the city with "," should be removed only the name of the city should be their others should be deleted

output required

| Name | City | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Toronto | Canada |
| Smith | Seattle | United States |
| Raj | Greater Toronto Area | Canada |

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you tried to use, this is not a freelance site, it is required that you show your efforts.

Comment: This time you were lucky someone actually answered your question. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

USE -`df['City'] = df['City'].str.split(',').str[0]`

Reproducible Code-

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd
  
# initialize list of lists
data = [['tom', 'Toronto ,ON','Canada'], [ "Raj","Greater Toronto Area, Canada","Canada"]]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'City','Country'])
  
# print dataframe.
df['City'] = df['City'].str.split(',').str[0]
df
```

Ouptut-

```
    Name    City                   Country
0   tom     Toronto                 Canada
1   Raj     Greater Toronto Area    Canada
```

Ref link-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40705480/python-pandas-remove-everything-after-a-delimiter-in-a-string